# Superposition of EM waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, superposition

> The following travelling Electromagnetic wave
>
> $E_x=0, E_y=E_0 \sin{(\omega t -kx)}, E_z=-2E_0 \sin{(\omega t +kx)}$ is
>
> (A) Linearly polarised (B) Elliptically polarised
> (C) Circularly polarised (D) Unpolarised
>
> > Source: KVPY SB/SX 2010 Q28

Since the two waves are travelling in opposite directions one can expect to get a standing wave but the electric field vectors are in perpendicular directions hence I'm not sure how that will work out (I have only studied about standing waves on string).

On analysing the superposition on particular points we get
Linearly polarized wave when $x=n\frac{\pi}{2k}$ and Elliptically polarised wave otherwise. Since there is different polarisation on different points is it correct to conclude that the wave is unpolarised?

P.S. : The official answer was (A)

Comment: They're inphase, so they would be linearly polarised

Comment: There is non zero phase difference which is also variable then how are they in phase?

Comment: What do you mean? There is zero phase difference between these two waves

Comment: Phase is the quantity written inside the trig functions taken mod 2π and they don't seem the same to me

Comment: K is wave vector, omega is frequency. The general wave should also have phi inside the trig function to indicate phase. They are both set to zero hence are in phase. I have no idea what you mean by mod 2pi

Comment: You are talking about initial phase zero. The term phase means the whole quantity $\omega t \pm kx + \phi$ even if $\phi$ is zero doesn't mean they are in phase. We can only say 'in phase' or 'out of phase' for waves in same direction. By mod 2π I mean sin(405°)=sin(405°-360°)=sin(45°)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text of the problem is incorrect and does not make sense. In the [original](http://www.kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/resources/SB_2010_Hindi.pdf), the waves move in the same direction.

Comment: Ohh I see. I only looked in the English version and in that paper they are moving in opposite directions. Thanks anyway